# how to fix validate some values in material ui table in reactjs and to validate some newly added table values

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing a mini task on `React.js` in that I have used `material UI` table and gave values through states and I wrote a `onChange` handler to edit that states.

If I click `edit` button all the states are changed to empty and if I click a `new` button new table is adding but I cant validate it, so how do I validate for the new tables and for the existing ones?

You can see my code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-flower-x402o).

I expected output should be if i click name only it should change name but not all fields and if click add new table should be added and that should be validated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon Analyzing the code, updated the fixes in the code sandbox. We need to update state when clicking 'edit' and '+' icon.

https://codesandbox.io/s/still-water-rpwnl

Comment: when creating a new row it should check the previous column values and it should create a new only after the previous columns was filled with all the values